# Cannot compile external modules into amd or commonjs when targeting es6 or higher

Tags: node.js, typescript

**test.ts**

```
export class Test {
    whatever(): Promise<any> {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

Trying to compile with old version:

```
$ tsc --version
message TS6029: Version 1.4.1.0
$ tsc --target es6 --module commonjs test.ts
$ cat test.js
var Test = (function () {
    function Test() {
    }
    Test.prototype.whatever = function () {
        return undefined;
    };
    return Test;
})();
exports.Test = Test;
```

This is fine. Now with new version:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/tsc --version
message TS6029: Version 1.5.0-beta
$ ./node_modules/.bin/tsc --target es6 --module commonjs test.ts
error TS1204: Cannot compile external modules into amd or commonjs when targeting es6 or higher.
```

Why is that? I am developing NodeJS application, so I have to use commonjs. Also, I need native promises, hence es6 target.

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/tsc --target es5 --module commonjs test.ts
test.ts(2,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are compiling to a target that supports ES6, you should use ES6 module imports, rather than commonjs or AMD.

```
import * as Promise from 'Promise';
```

Remove the `--module` flag when you compile if you supply `--target ES6`.